# Why is the 1D CNN accuracy low on time series?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I'm attempting to translate eeg data into an action using a 1D-CNN and had a few questions regarding my accuracy. I am aware I need to calculate the AUC score for each subject, but before doing that I noticed my accuracy is only hitting ~40% even when tuning the CNN. Anything that can point me in the right direction or shedding some light on if I am missing anything is helpful, Here is how my data is structured:

Subject EEG wave readings

```
[[[ 376.  462.  853. ...  417.   63.  109.]
  [ 296.  385.  807. ...  521.  140.  218.]
  [ 316.  391.  824. ...  343.  -79.   11.]
  ...
  [ 184.  224.  676. ...  104. -213.  -91.]
  [ 132.  199.  601. ...   93. -207. -155.]
  [ 165.  310.  539. ...   63. -234. -170.]]

 [[  80.  390.  422. ...  274.  -61.  163.]
  [ 324.  385.  686. ...  489.  193.  486.]
  [ 191.  407.  682. ...  327.   14.  339.]
  ...
  [ 175.  368.  412. ...  137. -202.  197.]
  [ 253.  293.  513. ...  260.  -75.  335.]
  [ 319.  475.  500. ...   50. -308.  131.]]

 [[1081.  752.  888. ...  235.  459.  597.]
  [1090.  917.  803. ...  244.  380.  484.]
  [1269. 1070. 1000. ...  258.  444.  490.]
  ...
  [1222.  984.  798. ...  369.  475.  562.]
  [1172.  916.  769. ...  182.  266.  425.]
  [1205.  890.  846. ...  147.  167.  241.]]

 ...

 [[ 287.  288.  612. ...  467.  263.  803.]
  [ 194.  191.  483. ...  547.  394.  833.]
  [ 125.  117.  415. ...  420.  216.  595.]
  ...
  [ 273.  181.  302. ...  130.  -94.  438.]
  [ 418.  462.  362. ...   60. -122.  302.]
  [ 447.  394.  403. ...  233.   33.  518.]]

 [[ 388.  533.  633. ...  391.  299.  659.]
  [ 183.  430.  440. ...  134.   51.  327.]
  [1154. 1165.  708. ...   21.   22.  194.]
  ...
  [2368. 1922.  981. ... -188. -202. -130.]
  [ 359.  270.  459. ...  280.  278.  482.]
  [ 259.  332.  581. ...  259.  226.  434.]]

 [[  70.  263.  344. ...   78.  241.  423.]
  [ 168.  321.  584. ...  290.  515.  515.]
  [  54.  229.  474. ...   57.  352.  454.]
  ...
  [ 141.  221.  530. ...   94.  357.  294.]
  [ 162.  254.  558. ...  173.  368.  375.]
  [ 139.  180.  563. ...  -29.  320.  286.]]]
```

Subject actions

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 9, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 32)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 7, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(64, 7, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

def generator(batch_size):
    while 1:
        x_time_data = np.zeros((batch_size, time_series//subsample, 32))
        yy = []
        for i in range(batch_size):
            random_index = np.random.randint(0, len(x_data) - time_series)
            x_time_data[i] = x_data[random_index:random_index + time_series:subsample]
            yy.append(y_data[random_index + time_series])
        yy = np.asarray(yy)
        yield x_time_data, yy

model.fit_generator(generator(32), steps_per_epoch=5000, epochs=3)
```

Results:

```
Epoch 1/3
5000/5000 [==============================] - 41s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2155 - accuracy: 0.3227
Epoch 2/3
5000/5000 [==============================] - 37s 7ms/step - loss: 0.1901 - accuracy: 0.3988
Epoch 3/3
5000/5000 [==============================] - 38s 8ms/step - loss: 0.1744 - accuracy: 0.4217
```

Comment: Did you train for how much epochs ? Why not Conv2D ? Also, use softmax in last layer, as is a multiclass problem.

Comment: 3 epochs. Based on what I've learned 1D CNN handles time series the best. Haven't tried Conv2D yet, but can give that a shot.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried without batch normalization? I've come across few instances where BN hurt performance than help.

Comment: And you might also want to be careful about dropout. This is not just any data, it is time series data and there's lot of issues with naively applying dropout on time series data.

Comment: @thushv89 I'll try that out. Is there a good explanation to why BN can hurt performance? Also I am not normalizing my data, that could also be an issue right?

Comment: @joethemow not really. It's just an observation I did a while ago in a problem I was working on. Don't remember all the details of that now. Might have had something to do with class imbalance.

Comment: About normalizing data, can't be too sure but I feel that might be the least of your problems given that modern initializers deal with unnormalized data decently. But if you can normalize the data, by all means do. Because that definitely helps. But keep in mind that this is time-series data. So you want to be careful how you normalize data.

Comment: Still having trouble figuring out what filter sizes I should have. Since my input size is (10, 32) I added 2 layers - `Conv1D(64, 7, activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 32))` and `Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')` followed by `MaxPooling1D(2)`  then a `Dense(6, activation='softmax')` layer but still getting very bad results. I tried adding more layers but my height is 1 after the MaxPooling layer.